# undefined value when accessing an element by its name

Tags: javascript, dom

In the following function I try to validate that an appropriate select value is chosen by a user. The alert popup box displays 'undefined' when I run the script. I need to get the element using its name rather than ID.

```
Sort table in =
<select name="SortIn">
<option value="Please Choose">Please Choose</option>
<option value="asc">Ascending order</option>
<option value="desc">Descending order</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA [ */

function validateForm()
{
    //Validates that form elements are not empty
            var test = document.getElementsByName('SortIn').value;
    alert(test1);
    if(test1 == null || test == "")
    {
        alert("Please select sorting order");
        return false;
    }
    else
        {
            return true;
        }
}

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName('SortIn')` returns a *nodelist*. You need to get the first element of that nodelist like so:

```
var test = document.getElementsByName('SortIn')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the element like this:

```
var test1 = document.getElementsByName('SortIn')[0].value;
                                                 ^
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BUk8z/)**

[getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns an array-like collection of elements, so you need to specify the index of the one you want.